# Data vanishing when going back on a screen

Tags: html, angularjs

So I am working on this webapp using `Angularjs` and `HTML`. Recently I made a dashboard kind of a thing with had some clients listed on the dashboard home screen (let this be screen A). On that screen I have a summary of those clients. When any on of the client is clicked, new screen appears with more data on the client. Let this be Screen B. Now on Screen B I have one more clickable tile which has some dates related to the client. Let this date screen be Screen C. Now when I come to screen C from A and then B and then go back to screen B and then again go back to screen C the data doesn't load anymore. I have to go back to screen A, re click the client card and the everything loads again. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angularjs use $state to record the history, screen B and screen C did not have a $state to match 。 you can add screen B and screen C to the route. and chick to B or C is to change the $tate. the second way is use history.pushState() to record the history.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I get what you were saying. Figured the solution out!